# Can you connect two GNOME-boxes via ssh?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, gnome, hadoop

I’m trying to set up 2 node Hadoop cluster using two lap-tops with GNOME-boxes, both running Ubuntu 17.10. The both laptops are connectes to the same wifi but the GNOME-boxes alone are not connected to the wifi. I need someone to explain to me the networking concepts of what I’m trying to do, is it possible at all?

Comment: I believe you'd like to use a **bridged adapter** as your virtual network adapter on the boxes, which will assign the boxes in IP address in the same network as your WiFi card, which will then allow you to ping/ssh your boxes from one another.

Comment: So I have put bridged adapter microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapter on both virtualboxes and when I type iconfig on one I have inet 10.0.2.15 on the other I don’t have inet at all.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't full understand what you are trying to do. Hadoop cluster connected via ethernet to laptop? Then bridged with your LAN? And you are also mentioning Windows.. Why is that when it is tagged Linux, and GNOME? Excuse me, I have no experience with the Hadoop equipment. But I can help you setup a bridged connection, if it has ethernet and you are in fact using GNOME.